# Puppeteer: Throwing custom error message within a javascript function being called using await in an async function

Tags: javascript, node.js, error-handling, async-await, puppeteer

I am using puppeteer to build a small app to automatically fill forms online. I am using Gmail as an example to test the functionality without clicking the submit button.

I open the Gmail URL and locate the username input field by using a function called `findInputFieldByName`. The code works fine, webpage opens and I can see puppeteer printing `test@gmail.com` in the username field.

The code is:

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

const gmailUrl='https://accounts.google.com/signin/v2/identifier?continue=https%3A%2F%2Fmail.google.com%2Fmail%2F&service=mail&sacu=1&rip=1&flowName=GlifWebSignIn&flowEntry=ServiceLogin';
const userName='test@gmail.com';
const findInputFieldByName = (page,inputName) => {
    return page.$('input[name="'+inputName+'"]');
}

(async () => {
    try {
    const Browser = await puppeteer.launch({headless:false,
                                        defaultViewport:{width:600,height:800}
                                        });
    const page=await Browser.newPage();

    page.on('load', () => console.log('Page loaded ' + page.url()));
    await page.goto(gmailUrl);

    const userNameElement = await findInputFieldByName(page,'identifier').catch(error => {
       console.log('The following error occurred: ' + error);
       });
    await userNameElement.type(userName,{delay:50});
    } catch(e) {console.log('main program error:' + e);
    }

})();
```

As you can see the code is looking for an input field whose name is `identifier` in the returned HTML. However, if I were to use a different name such as **identifier1**, which is not on the Gmail Login page, I want the code to throw  a custom error message saying "***Input field name identifier1 not found***" and the code should stop.

If I change

```
const userNameElement = await findInputFieldByName(page,'identifier').catch(error => {
           console.log('The following error occurred: ' + error);
           });
```

to

```
const userNameElement = await findInputFieldByName(page,'identifier1').catch(error => {
           console.log('The following error occurred: ' + error);
           });
```

I get the following error:

> main program error:TypeError: Cannot read property 'type' of null

I understand that this is because the function `findInputFieldByName` has not failed. It just returned a null object because there is no input field with the name **identifier1**. The code actually failed when it tried to type the email address.

However, my question is how can I throw an error from within the `findInputFieldByName` function so that it stops the at the `const userNameElement = await findInputFieldByName..` execution?

I have tried to use promises within the `findInputFiledByName` function as:

```
const findInputFieldByName = (page,inputName) => {
    let promise=new Promise(function (resolve,reject){
    var elm= page.$('input[name="'+inputName+'"]');
    if (elm.length>0) {
        resolve(elm);
    } else {
        reject(Error('Could not find input name ' + inputName));
    }
});
}
```

but I am getting the following message:

> main program error:TypeError: Cannot read property 'catch' of undefined
>   (node:12332) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Could not find input name identifier1
>
> at C:\Users\test1.js:11:10
>
> at new Promise (< anonymous >)
>
> at findInputFieldByName (C:\Users\test1.js:6:14)
>
> at C:\Users\test1.js:26:32
>
> at <  anonymous >
>
> at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:188:7) (node:12332) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise
>   rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async
>   function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was
>   not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1) (node:12332) [DEP0018]
>   DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In
>   the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the
>   Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.

How should I handle the custom errors? I am new to Javascript to any help is much appreciated.`enter code here`

Answer (score 3):

First of all, return the promise instead of assigning it to a variable.

```
const findInputFieldByName = (page, inputName) => {
  return new Promise(((resolve, reject) => { // <-- Return it
```

After that, you can `throw` error if need.

```
await findInputFieldByName(page,'identifier').catch(error => {
    throw ('The following error occurred: ' + error) // <-- pass the error to main program
});
```